# Dial a conference number and then automatically enter the participant code

Tags: phone-app

I am frequently joining conference calls (WebEx, GotoMeeting, etc) from my cell phone as I work remote occasionally. These calls usually have a static session number as they are recurring calls. Is there an application or a way to enter the number in the standard dialer to auto-enter the attendee / participant code?

Answer (score 0):

Go to contacts and edit the number. Add a 'comma' for a 2-3 second soft pause, add a 'semicolon' for a hard pause. Example,press 1 for English and enter extension and wait 4 seconds toconnect looks like this: ( 555-555-5555,,1;12345,,)